# Passing entry_id to json to get Playa children

Tags: playa, query

I need to be able to do pass the entry_id of the page being viewed into a json file to build a query.

I currently have a page setup that has a Playa field. I need to have a JSON file that will get the IDs of all of the Playa children so that I can pass those values to a map on the same page.

In the page, I have the following;

```
{exp:stash:set_list name="trail" parse_tags="yes" parse_depth="3"}  
    {exp:channel:entries channel="{channel}" status="open" limit="1" require_entry="yes"}

        {stash:trail_title}{title}{/stash:trail_title}

    {/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:stash:set_list}


{exp:stash:get_list name="trail"}

    <h2>About the {trail_title}</h2>

{/exp:stash:get_list}

<div class="mapwithborders">
    <div class="listing_map" data-api-url="trail-json"></div>
</div>
```

My 'trail-json.js' template has the following (but as you can see there is a hardcoded parent_entry_id;

```
{exp:query sql="SELECT child_entry_id AS entry_ids FROM exp_playa_relationships WHERE parent_entry_id = 2422"}
[
{exp:playa:children
    entry_id="{entry_ids}"
    field="trail_spots"
    channel="things-to-do"
    status="Open"
    backspace="1"
}
    {
        "entry_id": "{entry_id}",
        "title": "{title}",
        "latitude": "{thingtodo_latitude}",
        "longitude": "{thingtodo_longitude}"
    },{/exp:playa:children}
]
{/exp:query}
```

I would be grateful if someone could point me in the right direction to replace the hard-coded parent_entry_id.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

One easy way to solve this is to just use a segment variable. You can use segment_2 to hold whatever value you want to use for your query. So assuming you wanted to find data for the parent entry #2422, you'd load your JSON template with a URL of `/trail-json/2422`.

In your page template where you're setting the URL for your JSON you'd do:

```
<div class="listing_map" data-api-url="trail-json/2422"></div>
```

(Replace "2422" with a variable as appropriate, if I understand your setup it would be `{entry_id}`).

Then in your trail-json.js template where have have hard-coded the parent_entry_id in your query you would instead do:

```
WHERE parent_entry_id = {segment_2}
```

**Important note:** the Query module isn't safe to use with segment variables. So you should switch to using the [Active Record](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/activerecord) plugin instead of the Query module if you decide to use this approach.